# LUIS web interface crashed after import JSON file for Batch Testing or Import App

Tags: azure-language-understanding

When using LUIS web interface I encountered bugs below:

**1. Page freeze after adding intents or entities：** Start working after restart a new browser tab or few hours of waiting  .

**2. Can't publish app after Training：** All buttons on 'Publish' page turn gray and can't be pressed.Start working after restart a new browser tab or few hours of waiting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxH9J.png)

**3. Can't upload file for Batch Testing：** Uploading First test file of each app works fine, but uploading second file will cuz page freeze.

**4. Entities in Batch Testing result were replaced with tokens:** Can't recognized original utterances.

**5. Import App with Same JSON file will generate Different app:** I send same utterance to two different app which were all made of same JSON file, but got different result.

Thank you for reading my questions.
I sent those questions to Support message box but didn't get any reply so here is my last hope...

Comment: All those bugs have already been fixed and deployed except 3rd one. Batch testing bug has been fixed too and this change will be rolled out on Jan 15, 2018. If you have any further questions about LUIS, you can always reach out us at Luisuservoice@microsoft.com. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I really like the new version of LUIS.