# LUIS testing freezing, becoming unserponsive

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I've been trying to use batch testing to test my luis app and have been experiencing an annoying bug. Basically the LUIS app page will become unresponsive while the batch testing window is open.

The most similar issue I've seen can be found here: [LUIS web interface crashed after import JSON file for Batch Testing or Import App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47153187/5854011), with no answer yet.

My problem is also slightly different by the looks of it.

Experimenting has yielded the following results:

1. I can upload, test and view the results of 1 batch successfully sometimes. Sometimes the page will become unresponsive while I am looking at the results.
2. If I have successfully viewed the batch, but then close the batch testing window without deleting the batch, the next time I open the window the whole site will become unresponsive.
3. Recently opening the "Inspect" tab on the single utterance testing window has also begun making the page unresponsive.

I can submit images if needed, but the pages seem more or less the same after the bug has occurred, they simply stop working. Pressing buttons does nothing and I need to refresh the page if I want to get back to the bot's Dashboard/Build/Publish/Settings page.

The app has 18 intents, 12 entities, and a couple hundred utterances. I have tested it on a collaborator account and the bugs seems to occur there too. Not sure what other info might be relevant.

If anyone has experienced similar issues and can help I'd appreciate it. Being able to use the built in Batch Testing feature would be very useful.

Comment: FYI, I also experienced freezes on the `Train & Test` page regularly in the past 3 months, especially when being idle for a moment and trying to use it again

Comment: We've fixed this bug and the changes will be rolled out by Jan 15, 2018. Thanks for your patience.